# restlet debugging of server 'get'

Tags: java, debugging, restlet

I'm currently getting into restlet and have implemented the very basic hello world example of the server side:

```
import org.restlet.Server;
import org.restlet.data.Protocol;
import org.restlet.resource.Get;
import org.restlet.resource.ServerResource;

public class TestServer extends ServerResource {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        // Create the HTTP server and listen on port 8182
        new Server(Protocol.HTTP, 8182, TestServer.class).start();
    }

    @Get
    public String toString() {
        return "hello, world";
    }
```

The example is running but I have no clue how to debug the get method (toString)...if I set a breakpoint within the ToString method it does not stop during runtime. I'm using IntelliJ IDE. Thanks!

Comment: Do you use a logging framework? Maybe you can output a message on access. Do you get the desired result ("hello, world") ? You might also want to use the @Override annotation or change the method name.

Comment: yeah, I get the desired result...but for my real world app, debugging would be just mandatory, I think

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, I just need to do remote debugging. For IntelliJ see http://www.jetbrains.com/idea/webhelp/run-debug-configuration-remote.html

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps can you this to have more traces:

Engine.setLogLevel(Level.FINE);

Hope it helps you.
Thierry

Comment: remote debugging works now :) but anyways, thx for your contribution